# How to style a ImageField in Django Froms using widget

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, widget

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhR0E.png)

**Django Forms**

> How to style the Imagefield using widget in Django forms

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your question is not enough to provide an answer . Please provide enough code or explanation for this .

But for accessing the image field or styling it , use the following code :

```
from django import forms 

class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField(
        widget = forms.FileInput(
            attrs = {"id" : "image_field" , # you can access your image field with this id for css styling . 
                    , style = "height: 100px ; width : 100px ; " # add style from here .
                    }
            )
      
    ....
```